# Styling list item in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have written the following HTML code : 
My main focus is to align the list items - `HOME | All About Kittens | Feeding Your Kitten`
properly. It's currently appearing as a simple list. I want to make it like : 
[image] 
Here the list items are Home, Shop and collections and they are aligned horizontally 
Plus when you hover over an item it changes in color and a line appears below it
Any ideas how should I go about implementing this way

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.promo_banner {
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.logo img {
  max-width: 205px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" />
  </head>
  <div class="promo_banner">
    <div class="promo_banner__content">
      <p>
        <strong>Our Guide on Caring for Your Furry Feline Friend</strong>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="promo_banner-close"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="top_bar clearfix">
    <ul class="social_icons">
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
      />

      <div class="container">
        <span><a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i><a href="https://www.twitter.com"></a></span>
        <span><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></span>
        <span><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></span>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="logo text-align--center">
    <a href="https://store.linefriends.com" title="LINE FRIENDS INC">
      <img
        src="logo.jpeg"
        class="primary_logo lazyloaded"
        alt="LINE FRIENDS INC"
    /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="menu center">
      <li >
      <span>HOME</span>
       </li>  
       <li >
        <span>All About Kittens</span>
         </li>  
         <li >
          <span>Feeding Your Kitten</span>
           </li>  
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</html>
```

This is the logo.jpeg I am using in the HTML.
I wanted to make it like How the image line items appears in middle 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` to show navigation like the UI you mentioned.

Here's the demo: https://codepen.io/shubhamp-developer/pen/gOmmxOg

```
.nav .menu{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Preview:
[image]

To learn more about display flex, I would prefer to follow this super helpful link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I need one more small help not sure if I should open a new question.
The logo.jpeg file which I have on my local laptop spans the whole horizontal length. Whereas it should be in middle. Not sure how to align it. I am attaching the screenshot for that.

Comment: I have updated the code with the `Intro To Kittens` image. Which should appear like `Line Friends` in middle

Comment: Also while hovering over the buttons the color is not changing to green. It's like static only the `All about kittens` is green by default

Comment: Do upvote or accept this answer if this helped.

Comment: For the other issues, I would suggest learning some basic CSS tutorials out there first. That would help you a lot,
After that, if you still face issues then open another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Basically these two properties will fix this.**
display: flex;
justify-content: center;

Add these classes and remove background color from .nav .menu

```
.nav .menu{
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
  
.nav_wrapper {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Also wrap your `<div class="nav"></div>` in another div.nav_wrapper

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">
  <div class="nav">


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with the code you suggested : https://jsfiddle.net/pensee/q8g7kfxz/1/ It did center aligned the list but the color is not changing to green on hovering. Also the image with title `"LINE FRIENDS INC` is not center aligned. Not sure if I followed you properly. I am unable to include my local image in jsfiddle. Is there a way to do it. So that I could share proper fiddles..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eubahy2t/2/  

Here you go bro, edited only the last class and changed the border color and text color.  
Also changed the link from the image hosting.